# program to convert decimal to binary is not working for large outputs

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, long-integer

I made a program to convert decimal to binary but it is not working for big outputs.  I think I am not able to use `long long int` in my function properly.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int decimal_to_binary(int n)
{
    int x=1;
    long long int ans=0;
    while (x<=n){
        x*=2;
    }
    x/=2;
    while(x>0)
    {
        int lastdigit=n/x;
        n-=lastdigit*x;
        x/=2;
        ans=ans*10+lastdigit;
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    int input;
    long long int a;
    cout<<"input = ";
    cin>>input;
    a=decimal_to_binary(input);
    cout<<a;
}
```

For example,
if I input 30 it gives me expected output i.e. 11111.

The program gives correct output up to 1023 input,
but after that it gives me unexpected value.  For example,
if I input 1200 then output is 1420175408.

Comment: I can say that storing the result in a `long long` means nothing when your function says it will return an `int`.

Comment: I'm also curious as to why you're returning an integer type anyway. It might look like binary, but it's not.

Comment: *but it is not working for big outputs* -- Give us a sample of the input you are using.

Comment: You won't be able to store binary equivalent of a large number in a `long long int` variable. You need to use an integer array or a string.

Comment: Conversion decimal to binary is an I/O function, not something you should map one integral value to another (i.e. not what you're doing).   The mapping you're doing will map `1` to `1`, `2` to `10`, `3` to `11`, `4` to `100`, `5` to `101`, `6` to `110`, `7` to `111`, `8` to `1000`, `16` to `10000`.   Notice that the output value is substantially greater than the input for even small values, and grows much faster (in fact, exponentially).    And since `long long` holds a finite range of values.....

Comment: @sweenish thanks bro your comment made me understand what was the problem in function. i need to use long long int in to declear function

Comment: @JaMiT i have edited the problem if it helps to understand.

Comment: @paulmckenzie i have edited the code again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing a decimal number which is the binary representation of `n` reinterpreted as decimal.

If n>2047, `ans` will overflow a `std::int32_t`; if n>524287, `ans` will overflow a `std::int64_t` (the biggest signed 64-bit number is 9223372036854775807; `unsigned` would allow one more bit in `ans`).

The proper thing to return is a string. Try this:

```
std::string decimal_to_binary(int n)
{
    int x=1;
    std::string ans;
    while (x<=n){
        x*=2;
    }
    x/=2;
    while(x>0)
    {
        int lastdigit=n/x;
        n-=lastdigit*x;
        x/=2;
        ans=ans+(char)('0'+lastdigit);
    }
    return ans;
}
```